# Creating a child class of XElement that still keeps a reference to the original XElement and preserves the tree structure

Tags: xml, vb.net, xelement

To start things off, let me explain that I'm working with a class that inherits the `XElement` class.  The new class is called `MXElement`.  It adds some new functionality to it for navigating through the XML tree, as well as some more information regarding attributes, but that's not particularly important.  My problem is that I have an XML Tree filled with `XElement` objects.

However, when I create a new `MXElement` object from the `XElement` object before, it is just a copy of that object.  This means that any changes that I make to this object will not effect the original tree.

I suppose what I'm asking for is a way to build in the functionality for my `MXElement` class and keep references to the original `XElement` objects.  If possible, I would really prefer to keep `MXElement` a child class instead of building a lot of extension methods for `XElement`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reworked the entire idea and instead of using a child class, I used XPath to modify the tree.

For future ideas, I would like to know if there is still a solution to my original problem, but this is the solution I chose for my current problem.